# XSLT Dividing a text by seperator and give it an element and attribute number

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a text which has verse numbers.

Now, I want to separate the text by the verse numbers and give the single verses their number as an ID.

Since I did not know how to get the number from the source, I just gave them consecutive numbers, but I would prefer them to assign their actual number from the source, if it is possible. So that if one verse is missing the XSLT does not consecutively count, but skip a number.

But besides that, I have the problem, that I get an empty element `<l n="1"/>` at the beginning.

My XSLT somehow matches `<p>` too, I think, and therefore the actual n="1" becomes n="2".

How can I solve that?

My source:

> ```
> <root>
> <p>1 This is 2 a <hi rend="bold">beautiful</hi> example 3 poem 4 for showing! 5 my problem</p> 
> </root>
> ```

transformed with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/p">
        <p>
        <xsl:variable name="words" select="tokenize(text(),'(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)')" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(floor(count($words) div 1))">
            <xsl:variable name="vIndex" select="(.)" as="xs:integer"/>
            <l><xsl:attribute name="n"
            select="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$words[$vIndex]"/>
            </l>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I get is:

```
<root>
    <p>
      <l n="1"/>
      <l n="2"> This is </l>
      <l n="3"> a beautiful example </l>
      <l n="4"> poem </l>
      <l n="5"> for showing </l>
      <l n="6"> my problem</l>
   </p>
</root>
```

The wanted Output is:

```
<root>
    <p>
      <l n="1"> This is </l>
      <l n="2"> a <hi rend="bold">beautiful</hi> example </l>
      <l n="3"> poem </l>
      <l n="4"> for showing! </l>
      <l n="5"> my problem</l>
   </p>
</root>
```

---

Edit: I added an element into my Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `analyze-string` instead of `tokenize`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/p">
        <p>
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <l name="{regex-group(1)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
              </l>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
     </p>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you expect `p` elements to have element children you need a more complicated approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/p">
        <p>
          <xsl:variable name="children">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="wrap-number"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$children/node()" group-starting-with="n">
            <l n="{.}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/>
            </l>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p//text()" mode="wrap-number">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <n><xsl:value-of select="."/></n>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This however only works if it is ensured that the numbers for lines are contained in text node children of the `p` element, if they are also allowed in element children (e.g. `<p><span>1 This </span>2 is an example.</p>`) then more work is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I wanted. I'll stick with your answer since it seems that tokenize does not work with longer strings. But I realised that it does not copy elements within the string. I did not know that it would become a problem, therefore I did not include Elements in my example. I tried it with copy-of select, instead of value-of, but I came to the conclusion that I somehow have to enter the Element into the regex. For example, I have <hi rendition="bold">text</hi> in the string, which does not get copied. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: `analyze-string` operates on plain strings, not on trees of nodes. If you have child elements you want to preserve then the simple template suggested which does `analyze-string select="."` on the contents of the `p` element does not work. You would need to use a transformation in two steps where the first step makes sure the index numbers are transformed into elements you could group on (e.g. transform `<p>1 ... 2 ...</p>` into `<p><n>1</n>...<n>2</n>...</p>`) and the second then wraps as needed, by doing `<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="n">...</xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: @smk, I have edited my answer to show how to deal with `p` elements containing element children. The approach is as outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I tried so much, but would have never come up with something like that. I still have a long way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

The first element returned by `tokenize` will be what appears before the first number (in your case, an empty string).  So, assuming that you only want what appears after the first number, you have to remove the first element from the result of `tokenize` (using the `remove` function, for example).

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/p">
        <p>
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(text(),'(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0)')" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="words" select="remove($tokens, 1)" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(floor(count($words) div 1))">
            <xsl:variable name="vIndex" select="(.)" as="xs:integer"/>
            <l><xsl:attribute name="n"
            select="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$words[$vIndex]"/>
            </l>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```